# How to refresh a Canvas on a HTML bag?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this javascript program that draws a hundred circles on the screen and they can bounce around in the canvas on themselves. Currently I draw an empty rectangle over them to erase next generation of them. But is there a better way to erase and refresh a Canvas on a HTML page.

Code:

```
    function  drawScreen () {
    context.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
    //Box
    context.strokeStyle = '#000000'; 
    context.strokeRect(1,  1, theCanvas.width-2, theCanvas.height-2);

    update();
    testWalls();
    collide();
    render();
}
```

Here is all of the code if you want to try it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CH5EX7: Balls With Simple Interactions</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);  
function eventWindowLoaded() {
    canvasApp();
}

function canvasApp() {
    var numBalls = 200 ;
    var maxSize = 15;
    var minSize = 5;
    var maxSpeed = maxSize+5;
    var balls = new Array();
    var tempBall;
    var tempX;
    var tempY;
    var tempSpeed;
    var tempAngle;
    var tempRadius;
    var tempRadians;
    var tempvelocityx;
    var tempvelocityy;

    function  drawScreen () {
        context.fillStyle = '#EEEEEE';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, theCanvas.width, theCanvas.height);
        //Box
        context.strokeStyle = '#000000'; 
        context.strokeRect(1,  1, theCanvas.width-2, theCanvas.height-2);

        update();
        testWalls();
        collide();
        render();
    }

    function update() {
        var ball;
        for (var i =0; i <balls.length; i++) {
            ball = balls[i];
            ball.nextx = (ball.x += ball.velocityx);
            ball.nexty = (ball.y += ball.velocityy);
        }
    }

    function testWalls() {
        var ball;
        var testBall;

        for (var i =0; i <balls.length; i++) {
            ball = balls[i];

            if (ball.nextx+ball.radius > theCanvas.width) {
                ball.velocityx = ball.velocityx*-1;
                ball.nextx = theCanvas.width - ball.radius;

            } else if (ball.nextx-ball.radius < 0 ) {
                ball.velocityx = ball.velocityx*-1;
                ball.nextx =  ball.radius;

            } else if (ball.nexty+ball.radius > theCanvas.height ) {
                ball.velocityy = ball.velocityy*-1;
                ball.nexty = theCanvas.height - ball.radius;

            } else if(ball.nexty-ball.radius < 0) {
                ball.velocityy = ball.velocityy*-1;
                ball.nexty =  ball.radius;
            }
        }
    }

    function render() {
        var ball;
        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        for (var i =0; i <balls.length; i++) {
            ball = balls[i];
            ball.x = ball.nextx;
            ball.y = ball.nexty;

            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(ball.x,ball.y,ball.radius,0,Math.PI*2,true);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill();
        }
    }

    function collide() {
        var ball;
        var testBall;
        for (var i =0; i <balls.length; i++) {
            ball = balls[i];
            for (var j = i+1; j < balls.length; j++) {
                testBall = balls[j];
                if (hitTestCircle(ball,testBall)) {
                    collideBalls(ball,testBall);
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    function hitTestCircle(ball1,ball2) {
        var retval = false;
        var dx = ball1.nextx - ball2.nextx;
        var dy = ball1.nexty - ball2.nexty;
        var distance = (dx * dx + dy * dy);
        if (distance <= (ball1.radius + ball2.radius) * (ball1.radius + ball2.radius) ) {
              retval = true;
        }
        return retval;
    }

    function collideBalls(ball1,ball2) {
        var dx = ball1.nextx - ball2.nextx;
        var dy = ball1.nexty - ball2.nexty;

        var collisionAngle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

        var speed1 = Math.sqrt(ball1.velocityx * ball1.velocityx + ball1.velocityy * ball1.velocityy);
        var speed2 = Math.sqrt(ball2.velocityx * ball2.velocityx + ball2.velocityy * ball2.velocityy);

        var direction1 = Math.atan2(ball1.velocityy, ball1.velocityx);
        var direction2 = Math.atan2(ball2.velocityy, ball2.velocityx);

        var velocityx_1 = speed1 * Math.cos(direction1 - collisionAngle);
        var velocityy_1 = speed1 * Math.sin(direction1 - collisionAngle);
        var velocityx_2 = speed2 * Math.cos(direction2 - collisionAngle);
        var velocityy_2 = speed2 * Math.sin(direction2 - collisionAngle);

        var final_velocityx_1 = ((ball1.mass - ball2.mass) * velocityx_1 + (ball2.mass + ball2.mass) * velocityx_2)/(ball1.mass + ball2.mass);
        var final_velocityx_2 = ((ball1.mass + ball1.mass) * velocityx_1 + (ball2.mass - ball1.mass) * velocityx_2)/(ball1.mass + ball2.mass);

        var final_velocityy_1 = velocityy_1;
        var final_velocityy_2 = velocityy_2;

        ball1.velocityx = Math.cos(collisionAngle) * final_velocityx_1 + Math.cos(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * final_velocityy_1;
        ball1.velocityy = Math.sin(collisionAngle) * final_velocityx_1 + Math.sin(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * final_velocityy_1;
        ball2.velocityx = Math.cos(collisionAngle) * final_velocityx_2 + Math.cos(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * final_velocityy_2;
        ball2.velocityy = Math.sin(collisionAngle) * final_velocityx_2 + Math.sin(collisionAngle + Math.PI/2) * final_velocityy_2;

        ball1.nextx = (ball1.nextx += ball1.velocityx);
        ball1.nexty = (ball1.nexty += ball1.velocityy);
        ball2.nextx = (ball2.nextx += ball2.velocityx);
        ball2.nexty = (ball2.nexty += ball2.velocityy);
    }

    theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasOne');
    context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');

    for (var i = 0; i < numBalls; i++) {
        tempRadius = 5;
        var placeOK = false;
        while (!placeOK) {
            tempX = tempRadius*3 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*theCanvas.width)-tempRadius*3);
            tempY = tempRadius*3 + (Math.floor(Math.random()*theCanvas.height)-tempRadius*3);
            tempSpeed = 4;
            tempAngle =  Math.floor(Math.random()*360);
            tempRadians = tempAngle * Math.PI/ 180;
            tempvelocityx = Math.cos(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;
            tempvelocityy = Math.sin(tempRadians) * tempSpeed;

            tempBall = {x:tempX,y:tempY, nextX: tempX, nextY: tempY, radius:tempRadius, speed:tempSpeed, angle:tempAngle, velocityx:tempvelocityx, velocityy:tempvelocityy, mass:tempRadius};
            placeOK = canStartHere(tempBall);
        }
        balls.push(tempBall);
    }

    function canStartHere(ball) {
        var retval = true;
        for (var i =0; i <balls.length; i++) {
            if (hitTestCircle(ball, balls[i])) {
                retval = false;
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
   function gameLoop() {
            window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
            drawScreen()    
        }

    gameLoop();


}

</script>

</head>
<body> 
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">

<canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="500">
 Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
</canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have placed the newest working code here in case someone is looking at this post as a reference down the road. The clear the canvas is down differently and works very well.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Moving In Circle</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', eventWindowLoaded, false);  
function eventWindowLoaded() {
    canvasApp();

}

 function canvasApp() {
    var radius = 100;
    var circle = {centerX:250, centerY:250, radius:125, angle:0}
    var ball = {x:0, y:0,speed:.1};

    theCanvas = document.getElementById('canvasOne');
    context = theCanvas.getContext('2d');

    function erraseCanvas() {
        context.clearRect(0,0,theCanvas.width,theCanvas.height);
    }

    function drawScreen () {
        erraseCanvas();

        ball.x = circle.centerX + Math.cos(circle.angle) * circle.radius;
        ball.y = circle.centerY + Math.sin(circle.angle) * circle.radius;
        circle.angle += ball.speed;

        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.beginPath();
            context.arc(ball.x,ball.y,15,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }

    function gameLoop() {
         window.setTimeout(gameLoop, 20);
         drawScreen()   
    }

    gameLoop();
}

</script>

</head>
<body>  
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px;">

<canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="500">
 Your browser does not support the HTML 5 Canvas. 
</canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the most popular methods are `fillRect`, `clearRect` or resetting the canvas dimensions. here's a performance breakdown: http://jsperf.com/canvas-clear-speed/25

Answer (score 5):

clear Canvas
      `context.clearRect ( x , y , w , h );`

x:The x-coordinate, in pixels 
y:The Y-coordinate, in pixels 
w:The width, in pixels 
h:The height, in pixels

Comment: This is all that needs to be done to clear a canvas on an HTML page.

Answer (score 3):

Resizing the canvas will cause the canvas to get cleared.

```
myCanvasElement.width+=0; // causes the canvas to resize (to the same size)
```

Be warned this will also clear your transformations