# Pixels left after clearing a circle in HTML5 canvas due to antialiasing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I tried to draw and then clear a circle in HTML5 Canvas.

Below is the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Canvas Circle Draw & Clear</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>

<script>
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50,50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.clip();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0 , 100, 100);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the page with Firefox and Safari, there's a faint green circle left. When using Chrome and Opera, the circle is completely cleared. There's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hulloanson/k13un73u/) with the same code as above. So far I've tested on both Windows and OSX with the same result.

I understand that is the result of anti-aliasing, but I wonder why the generated pixels are not erased? How can I completely remove the circle in Firefox/Safari?

**Edit:** I don't want to clear the whole canvas. Just want to remove the circle completely without affecting all other pixels (Thanks to @relfor reminding me that).

Comment: Interesting question, I found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22812281 which suggests a way to clear the canvas by adding 0 to the width of the canvas. It will unfortunately clear your entire canvas.

Comment: Oh. You touch on a point that I missed. I don't want to clear the whole canvas.

Comment: Don't use clip for this. You'll get better results with globalCompositeOperations. And for the anti-aliasing just make your erasing circle a bit larger : https://jsfiddle.net/9vv9s2k6/

Comment: Oh that's great. So somehow clipping does not include anti-aliased pixels?

Comment: Canvas is an additive render. It is not intended to understand the pixels it renders and hence erase then. Some options (A) You can create a undo buffer and undo the circle. (B) Layer your rendering with offscreen layers (canvases). To remove the circle just re-render the layers without the circle (or clear the circle layer) (C) Copy the canvas before you draw the circle, draw the circle. Set the comp mode on the copy to "difference" and draw the canvas with circle on top of the copy. To erase, invert the circled canvas, set comp to "lighter" draw copy on top, and invert again.(D) Use SVG